# Adding our data files into a custom multi-prompt template via langchain?

Tags: openai-api, langchain, py-langchain, azure-openai

I'm developing a tool using langchain and openAI which requires the use of some custom datasets that I feed in. I am able to get this working using the following.

```
llm =  AzureChatOpenAI(openai_api_base=OPENAI_API_BASE, 
                    openai_api_key=OPENAI_API_KEY, 
                    deployment_name=deployment_name, 
                    model_name=deployment_name, 
                    openai_api_version=OPENAI_DEPLOYMENT_VERSION)

agent = create_pandas_dataframe_agent(llm,
    [dataset1, dataset2],
    verbose=False,
    agent_type=AgentType.OPENAI_FUNCTIONS,
)
```

But problem is, I need to insert prompt template into the mix. I have a custom prompt as follows:

```
from langchain import PromptTemplate

multi_input_template = """
You are an expert in {data}.
{query}
"""

multi_input_prompt = PromptTemplate(input_variables=["data", "query"], template=multi_input_template)
```

Which I can query as follows:

```
multi_input_prompt.format(data="AIDS", query="What diagnosis are suitable if presenting with cancer?")
```

But problem is, if I do this, I cant integrate my custom datasets into the mix.

Any recomendations are greatly appreciated.
I am using langchain==0.0.336 and langchain-experimental==0.0.42

Answer (score -1):

It seems like you want to integrate your custom datasets into the prompt template along with the query. If I understand correctly, you want to use your datasets as part of the input to the model.

You can do this by making some changes in your template:

```
multi_input_template = """
You are an expert in {data}.
{query}
Here is some information from dataset 1: {dataset1}
And here is some information from dataset 2: {dataset2}
"""

multi_input_prompt = PromptTemplate(
    input_variables=["data", "query", "dataset1", "dataset2"],
    template=multi_input_template
)

formatted_prompt = multi_input_prompt.format(
    data="AIDS",
    query="What diagnosis are suitable if presenting with cancer?",
    dataset1=dataset1,
    dataset2=dataset2
)
```